# Filter out extra headers in middle of table

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to import a very large data file. It is a text file structured like

```
***** Information about Data ***********
Information about data
Information about Data
Information about Data

Information about Data

    Col1     Col2
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
     ...(10k+ lines)
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
***** Information about Data ***********
Information about data
Information about Data
Information about Data

Information about Data

    Col1     Col2
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
     ...(10k+ lines)
     1.0      1.0
     1.0      1.0
```

and repeats some arbitrary number of times. The number of lines between headers varies and the total file is >1 million lines.

Is there a method of stripping this header without looking line-by-line? I have written a line-by-line search, but that is too slow to be practical.

The header is varies slightly each time it is displayed.

Comment: Is `Header info`  actually `Header info`?

Comment: No, I will edit accordingly

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` accepts input from anything that can feed it line by line.  Since it already reads a file with `readline`, inserting your line-by-line search in the pipeline won't slow it down. With `pandas'` compiled reader it might be a different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file is named `test.txt`

- read in entire file as a string
- `split` on `'\n*'`

  ```
       new line
               \ 
    1.0      1.0
  ***** Information about Data ***********
   \
    followed by astricks
  ```
- `rsplit` results by `'\n\n'` and take last

  ```
         first new line
                       \
  Information about Data

   \
    second new line
      Col1     Col2
       1.0      1.0
       1.0      1.0
       1.0      1.0
  ```
- `read_csv`
- `pd.concat`

---

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def rtxt(txt):
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)

fname = 'test.txt'

pd.concat(
    [rtxt(st.rsplit('\n\n', 1)[-1])
     for st in open(fname).read().split('\n*')],
    ignore_index=True
)

    Col1  Col2
0    1.0   1.0
1    1.0   1.0
2    1.0   1.0
3    1.0   1.0
4    1.0   1.0
5    1.0   1.0
6    1.0   1.0
7    1.0   1.0
8    1.0   1.0
9    1.0   1.0
10   1.0   1.0
11   1.0   1.0
```